# AMCL publishing simple question

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I have successfully written a python robot controller to control my lidar-bearing robot.
t is based on a Raspberry Pi 3 and can be commanded through an RC remote (with a receiver) or via the cmd_vel topic, whichever I choose.
It also works quite nice when visualized in Rviz, odometry drifts are relatively low but will remain always due to many reasons on which I have little control of.
So I want to use AMCL to localize. It had worked great when I created the simulation in Gazebo, but it was ideal, and now in the real world it isnt so.
To my question: on the AMCL documentation [here](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl), at the bottom of the page, it says that AMCL estimates the transformation between /map and /base_link. But my Raspi node is the one publishing the Tf between /odom and /base_link... and it would not be wise to double-publish that. Would it be safe to say that the AMCL publishes the Tf between /map and /odom in order to compensate for the odometry drift?

Thanks in advance,
Steve

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267046/amcl-publishing-simple-question/) by [StevenCoral](https://answers.ros.org/users/30608/stevencoral/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2017-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, AMCL is the responsible for publishing the map->odom tf.
That said, the statement "AMCL estimates the transformation between /map and /base_link" is also correct.

According to the link you provided ( http://wiki.ros.org/amcl#Transforms):

"During operation amcl estimates the transformation of the base frame (~base_frame_id) in respect to the global frame (~global_frame_id) **but it only publishes the transform between the global frame and the odometry frame** (~odom_frame_id)."

What all this means is that it is computing where your base_link is with respect to the map, but in order to maintain a smooth and continuous odometry (provided by your driver), it corrects the pose of base_link by adjusting the map->odom transofrm.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2017-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [StevenCoral](https://answers.ros.org/users/30608/stevencoral/) on 2017-07-30**:
Thank you, this clarified things up